# Choropleth Map - Folium Data Won't Show

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, folium, choropleth

```py
import folium
import pandas as pd

address = 'Columbus, GA'

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="ga_explorer")
location = geolocator.geocode(address)
latitude = location.latitude
longitude = location.longitude
print('The geograpical coordinate of Columbus, GA are {}, {}.'.format(latitude, longitude))


df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Jill\Downloads\Income__by_Zip_Code__2018_River_valley.csv', usecols=('PlanningRegion','GEOID','aMeanHHIncome_e18','TotPop_e18'), encoding='utf-8')
#("https://opendata.atlantaregional.com/datasets/income-by-zip-code-2018/geoservice?geometry=-94.056%2C23.342%2C-78.236%2C36.615&orderBy=PlanningRegion&orderByAsc=false&where=PlanningRegion%20%3D%20%27River%20Valley%27")
zip_data = "https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/c917469836c2472e9b80ec0b57a24468_111.geojson?where=PlanningRegion%20%3D%20'River%20Valley'%20AND%20%20(GEOID%20%3D%20'31820'%20OR%20GEOID%20%3D%20'31901'%20OR%20GEOID%20%3D%20'31903'%20OR%20GEOID%20%3D%20'31904'%20OR%20GEOID%20%3D%20'31906'%20OR%20GEOID%20%3D%20'31907'%20OR%20GEOID%20%3D%20'31909')%20"
df=df.drop([0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,30])

map_columbus = folium.Map(location=[latitude, longitude], zoom_start=10)

map_columbus.choropleth(
    geo_data=zip_data,
    data=df,
    columns=['GEOID','aMeanHHIncome_e18'],
    key_on='feature.properties.id',
    fill_color='YlGnBu', 
    fill_opacity=1, 
    line_opacity=1,
    legend_name='Average Household Income',
    smooth_factor=0)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(map_columbus)      

map_columbus
```

Problem description:

I'm experiencing an issue while creating a folium choropleth map in jupyter notebook. Everything is showing as expected except the data that should be in the map. Instead, the geodata is left blank, not filled with color.

Comment: Please, provide the csv file. Thanks.

Comment: The CSV is a filtered spreadsheet from this URL: "https://opendata.atlantaregional.com/datasets/income-by-zip-code-2018/data?geometry=-85.670%2C32.273%2C-83.817%2C32.679&orderBy=ARCModelingArea&selectedAttribute=aHHMeanEarnings_e18&where=PlanningRegion%20%3D%20%27River%20Valley%27"

Answer (score 0):

As long as the `zip_data` you are working with is `Income__by_Zip_Code__2018.geojson`, you should use in `map_columbus.choropleth()`:

```
key_on='feature.properties.GEOID'
```

Comment: It's still not seeming to work, not returning any color indicating value